# prolog lists in graphs

Tags: prolog

Hi I have this prolog program and graph

[image: graph]

```
node(node_1,[numbers_line]).
node(node_2,[numbers_line, letters_line]).
node(node_3,[numbers_line]).
node(node_4,[numbers_line]).
node(node_5,[numbers_line, animal_line, colour_line]).
node(node_6,[numbers_line]).
node(node_a,[letters_line]).
node(node_b,[letters_line]).
node(node_c,[letters_line]).
node(node_cat, [animal_line]).
node(node_dog, [animal_line]).
node(node_red, [colour_line]).
node(node_blue, [colour_line]).
node(node_green, [colour_line]).
```

I then have a rule that states

```
sameline(X,Y,Line).
sameline(X,Y,Line):-node(X,Line), node(Y,Line).
```

if both nodes are on the same line (e.g `node_3` and `node_4`)
the program outputs

```
true;
Line=numbers_line.
```

however if both nodes are on the same line but one is on multiple lines 
(e.g `node_a` and `node_2`) the program outputs

```
true;
false
```

however as both nodes are on the `letters_line` it should output

```
true;
Line = letters_line
```

what am I missing any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
sameline(X, Y, Line) :-
  node(X, LineListX),
  node(Y, LineListY),
  member(Line, LineListX),
  member(Line, LineListY).
```

Your first `sameline/3` clause

```
sameline(X,Y,Line).
```

is wrong because it says that *every* couple of nodes is in the same line without set (unify!) a value for line.

Your second `sameline/3` clause

```
sameline(X,Y,Line):-node(X,Line), node(Y,Line).
```

is wrong because it says that a couple of nodes is in the same line if the list of the lines of the first node is equal (with the same order!) to the list of the lines of the second node and set `Line` (unify it!) with the common list of the lines.

So `node_3` and `node_4` resulting in the same line because `[numbers_line]` (the list containig a single element `numbers_line`) is equal to `[numbers_line]`. And `Line` should be unified with `[numbers_line]` (the list), not with `numbers_line`.

So `sameline(node_a, node_2, Line)` should return false (the second clause) because `[letters_line]` is different from `[numbers_line, letters_line]`

The correct mode is detect the list of lines `LineListX` for `X`

```
node(X, LineListX),
```

detect the list of lines `LineListY` for `Y`

```
node(Y, LineListY),
```

unify `Line` with a single element of `LineListX` (it try with every element of `LineListX`)

```
member(Line, LineListX),
```

and check if `Line` is a member of LineListY too

```
member(Line, LineListX).
```

If this last condition is true, `sameline` return true and `Line` is unified with the common element in line lists.